# Schema.org - JSON-LD - Where to Place?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I am looking to use JSON-LD for schema on a website. (Schema meaning schema.org data.) I know how to write the data but my question is is there a prefered location in my code to insert this data? In other words, should the JSON-LD always be in the `head`, `body`, etc.?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

From the perspectives of Schema.org, JSON-LD, and the possibly extracted RDF, it should not matter. The data is the same, no matter from where in the document it got extracted.

From the perspective of HTML5:

If it’s data about your page (or what this page is about), you could place the `script` element in the `head`, as the [`head` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#the-head-element)

> […] represents a collection of metadata for the Document

But of course it would not be wrong to use `body` for this instead. It’s just that you shouldn’t use `head` for data that is not about your page or what it represents.

Comment: It try to understand the last line of your high quality answer. Do you mean that if the `ld+json` is about the organisation _as a whole_ and not on _the current page perse_ it should __not__ go in the `<head>`?

Comment: @theking2: Correct. But, as mentioned in the first part, it doesn’t affect the structured data at all (i.e., when extracting/parsing the JSON-LD, it doesn’t matter where in the HTML document it’s placed).

Comment: true. It probably is a matter of best-practices

Answer (score 117):

The data can be placed anywhere. From [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/events/performers?rd=1#option_1_add_html_event_markup_directly):

> The data, enclosed within the `<script type="application/ld+json">` ...
>   `</script>` tags as shown in the examples below, may be placed **in either
>   the `<HEAD>` or `<BODY>` region** of the page that displays that event.

You can also use [data dynamically fetched using AJAX](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/events/performers?rd=1#will_google_recognize_event_markup_in_dynamically_generated_eg_ajax_web_pages):

> JSON-LD markup inserted by Javascript that runs upon initial page load
>   can be recognized.

**Update** (as pointed by [Antony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355149/antony) in the comments)

The [latest documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data) says:

> [JSON-LD is a] JavaScript notation embedded in a  tag in the page **head or body**... Google can read JSON-LD data when it is dynamically injected into the page's contents, such as by JavaScript code or embedded widgets in your content management system.

Comment: The new URL is https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data. There is a table 2/3 way down, with a "Description and Placement" column

Comment: This video on Google Search Central channel also backs up this answer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lI6EtxjoyDU

Answer (score -2):

if you choose to insert in the `<body>`, you got to do it like this:

```
<p class="companyName" vocab="http://schema.org/" resource="#manu" typeof="Organization">
   <span property="name">ShopTech Media</span>
   <img property="logo" src="https://yoursite.com/logo.png" />
   <a property="url" href="http://www.yoursite.com">Home page</a>
</p>
<p typeof="contactPoint">
  <span property="contactType">Customer Service:</span>
<span property="telephone">+45-xxxxxxx</span>
</p>
```

below is the script code to insert your structured data in the `<head>` tag

```
<script type="application/ld+json"> 
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "url": "http://www.shoptech.media",
  "logo": "https://shoptech.media/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/cropped-logo-sm.png",
  "contactPoint": [{
    "@type": "ContactPoint",
    "telephone": "+45-65711114",
    "contactType": "customer service"
  }]
}
</script>
```

check the documentation at [general structured data guideline](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies)

Comment: Are you able to back up your answer with some sources or more information? Other answers say something different, and I can't find anything in the link you provided.