# How to implement JSON-LD?

Tags: html, json-ld

I’ve been reading about JSON-LD today and I understand its purpose, format, and that I can put it in a script tag; however, I don’t understand the following:

1. Where can this data reside other than in a script tag for a website? I've been expecting to find JSON-LD content in either script tags or included .json files when I view the page source of websites that say they use JSON-LD, but since I haven't seen any of this, it leads me to believe it must be accessible in a different location.
2. How is this collection of information usually constructed for larger websites?
3. How do other sites find the JSON-LD files, objects, or data to use that information?

It would be really great to see an example in the wild.

Answer (score 6):

In HTML5, the [`script` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) can be used as data block:

> When used to include data blocks (as opposed to scripts), the data must be embedded inline, the format of the data must be given using the `type` attribute, the `src` attribute must not be specified, and the contents of the `script` element must conform to the requirements defined for the format used.

So a `script` element containing JSON-LD could look like this:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
     "@context": "http://example.com",
     "@type": "Example"
    }
</script>
```

You [may place](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28688394/1591669) the `script` element(s) in the `head` and/or in the `body`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking where to put it on your web site's page. It would reside in between `<script></script>` in the `<head>` which is as simple as it gets.

[Here is the source of all information JSON-LD](http://json-ld.org/)