# Where to paste my Schema.org "LocalBusiness" info?

Tags: schema.org

Can I paste my Schema.org `LocalBusiness` info in the `head` of my webpage or should it be inserted in the `body`?

My concern is that all those pieces of info are already written somewhere on the page (but not at once) and I don't want to have them twice, once for the markup info, once for the normal reader.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the syntax **Microdata** or **RDFa**, you would ideally apply it to your existing markup. Most of the time you don’t have to duplicate your content.

If you are using the syntax **JSON-LD**, you add a separate [data block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30798784/1591669) (in a `script` element; see this [answer about its placement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28688394/1591669)). You always have to duplicate your content.