# How to move JSON-LD from in-line to in-a-file?

Tags: json, jsonp, json-ld

I have an `HTML` document with `JSON-LD` published as follows:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
           "@context": {
               "gs1": "http://vocab.gs1.org/v1#",
               "xsd":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
           },
           "@id": "retailer:12345",
           "@type": "gs1:Offering",
           "gtin13":"5011476100111",
           "gs1:hasPrice": {
               "gs1:price": "2.49",
               "gs1:priceTypeCode": "USD",
               "@type":"gs1:Price"
           }
      }
</script>
```

This works as expected (meaning it is valid and visible using `Google Structured Data Testing Tool` and `Structured Data Linter`)

Using `Same Origin` (**not** `Cross Origin`), how to move the in-line `JSON-LD` to a file?

This approach fails:

```
<script type="application/ld+json" src="_URL_.json"></script>
```

This approach also fails:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "_URL_.json",
                dataType: 'json',
                });        
        });
</script>
```

**How to correct my approach to create a solution where the JSON-LD is in file on my server, not in the HTML?**

Next, assume my site is CORS-enabled.

**How to publish the JSON-LD structure in a JSONP format so that another domain can subscribe to the JSON-LD data?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate your script tag dynamically:

```
<script>
  // do some ajax, get the JSON-LD as `data` and then...
  $.ajax(...).done(function(data) {
    var el = document.createElement('script');
    el.type = 'application/ld+json';
    el.text = JSON.stringify(data);
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(el);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This works. However, as @unor warned, Google structure data tool does not acknowledge the `stringify(data)` as JSON-LD because it is an external reference. I need to reconsider my approach. My interim solution will be to follow @unor advice and identify the URI using `<link rel="alternate" href="URI" type="application/ld+json" />`

Answer (score 2):

Tools like the [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) or the [Structured Data Linter](http://linter.structured-data.org/) don’t support external references. And probably many consumers of your JSON-LD neither.

If you want to do it anyway, you would have to use a [`link` instead of a `script` element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30880613/1591669), because for the use as [data block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30798784/1591669), the `script` element may not have a `src` attribute.

The variant with including the JSON-LD dynamically might work for consumers that support JavaScript for that purpose. ([Google seems to support it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29066759/1591669); maybe it’s only their testing tool that can’t use it.)

Comment: Would you show me what your `link` structure would look like? If I can make it work, I'll accept the answer. I'll move the `JSON-LD` format for `JSONP` to a new question, as I see that as an alternative; and I need to publish the `JSON-LD` as `JSONP` for other reasons.

Comment: @JayGray: I don’t know any consumer that supports fetching external JSON-LD via `link`; if there’s one that supports it, they might expect a specific link type. For other RDF serializations (like RDF/XML, Turtle etc.), the `alternate` link type is often used: `<link rel="alternate" href="/example.foo" type="application/ld+json" />`