# Including JSON-LD or Microdata from a file in an HTML page?

Tags: file, schema.org, microdata, json-ld

Is it possible to include JSON-LD or Microdata from a file in an HTML page?

I know it can be inserted directly, I'm looking for a way to use external files instead.

I can use either JSON-LD or Microdata format. I need to be able to include from a file, if possible, please advise.

Comment: Related questions: [Does JSON-LD have to be embedded?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30864619/1591669) · [How to move JSON-LD from in-line to in-a-file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33236198/1591669)

Comment: Do you have specific consumers for the structured data in mind?

Comment: It's google structured data schema.

Answer (score 0):

You can [dynamically embeded](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/schema-org) JSON-LD in HTML

> Google can read JSON-LD data even when it is dynamically injected into the page's contents, such as by Javascript code or embedded "widgets".

but you can't just directly reference a JSON-LD file. You need to eventually embed it into the HTML. That should only require a couple of lines of JavaScript though.

Comment: Do you have a specific way to implement that? Also it doesn't have to be jason-ld, microdata would work too.

Comment: Write a small JavaScript function which looks for `link` tags with `type="application/ld+json"` in the header, do a XHR request for each of them and embed the result in script blocks in your document.