# Where to find my HTML pages in Virtualmin?

Tags: json-ld, virtualmin

I would like to add Schema.org’s `LocalBussines` with JSON-LD to my website, but I can´t find the `<head>` on my root file on the server. I’m using Virtualmin.

I already did this for some WordPress websites, but now I’m struggling with this one.

What am I missing here? Anyone knows?

Comment: Isn’t Virtualmin just a webhosting control panel (I’m not sure, don’t know it), and your website gets managed in some other way (e.g., with an installed CMS like WordPress etc.)?

Comment: Yes, Virtualmin it´s a webhosting where i manage files like `.htaccess`. It shouldn´t be there (virtualmin) where in find the pages to add a schema code?

Comment: Well, you did create/write your website somehow, where you put in all the HTML, your content etc. This is the place where you add JSON-LD. By the way, you [don’t have to use the `head` element for JSON-LD](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28688394/1591669): you could put it into each page’s `body`.

Comment: I didn´t, that´s why. And now i need to find it and i can´t. By the way, i´m a newbie on this, so sorry for my lack of knowledge. Anyone knows how to find the  HTML and content?

Answer (score 0):

HTML, and all apps, in a default Virtualmin configuration, would be located in /home/domainname/public_html

This is pretty standard across many types of shared hosting and not unique to Virtualmin. You can access files via ssh, FTP (if enabled by your web server owner), the File Manager in Virtualmin, the Upload and Download module in Virtualmin, or the Edit Web Pages module in Virtualmin (which is a simple WYSIWYG HTML editor; note Edit Web Pages only exists in Virtualmin Professional at this time).

We also have a new file manager in development that includes a nice HTML5 text editor with syntax highlighting and such. It should be out in the next major version of Virtualmin in a few days. It will be included in both Virtualmin GPL and Virtualmin Professional.

Disclaimer: I work on Virtualmin.

Comment: Wow. That's a really nice explanation that i appreciate a lot. But from what i understand (almost nothing on this subject) is that my website it´s coded on getting data from server (am I saying right?) and i can´t figure out how to add a `json-ld` schema to my main page because of that same reason.

Comment: I don't understand your explanation for what's happening. It sounds like you're thinking Virtualmin is a content management system, maybe? But, it's not. If there is a content management system running on the system, it will be something other than Virtualmin; Virtualmin does not directly determine web page data. It manages the stuff above that: users, domains, databases, apps, etc. You'll need to figure out what is actually producing your web pages. On a Virtualmin system, that could be public_html (for php apps), or something else in /home.

Comment: If the application that is producing your pages was installed by Virtualmin, it will be listed in the Install Scripts page, which will also provide information like the database name, and the installation path. Modifying the schema would be something you'd do in your web application...not in Virtualmin. Basically, you need to figure out what is generating your web pages...if they aren't plain HTML, there will be an application installed somewhere that is doing it. That's what you need to figure out how to use, for this task.

Comment: Thank you both for the awesome explanation. I think i start to understand how this works, but i still have some doubts. I have a content management system/back-office(is this the same?) where i create new products but the thing is, i would like to access the HMTL of that exact page i just created but i cant find it. It´s that HTML page somewhere in virtualmin or in my cms? Btw, in virtualmin i use cpainel to manage files like.htaccess.

Comment: I think you're still pretty confused. ;-) But, keep researching, and you'll get it figured out. I don't really know how to guide you beyond this point, however, as there's no new information in your comment. The content management system/back-office may be the same thing, I don't know; what product or project are you using for that? There will probably not be an HTML page stored on the filesystem, if you're using a CMS or similar. It will be generated from templates with data from the database. Those might be easily editable, or might require you to know PHP or Python or Ruby or whatever.