# Google structured data for Events

Tags: seo, schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

I want to show events on Google, so I have created this JSON-LD:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
[{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "TestEvent",
  "name": "Rohit Patil Event",
  "startDate": "2014-10-10T19:30",
  "location": {
     "@type": "Place",
     "name": "Warner Theatre",
     "address": "Washington, DC"
  },
  "offers": {
     "@type": "Offer",
     "url": "https://www.etix.com/ticket/1771656"
  }
}
]
</script>
```

I have tested this in testing tool and having 0 error.

How can I use this code to work on Google? What is the best file to place this code?

Answer (score 0):

You add the `script` element to the page about this event, either [in the `head` or in the `body`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28688394/1591669).

It becomes clearer if you use Microdata or RDFa instead of JSON-LD, because there you have to mark up your existing content. With JSON-LD you duplicate the content, but it still should be placed where the actual/visible content is.

Comment: If I have update my reviews then how much time Google will take to reflect on results? any guesses??

Comment: @RohitPatil: I think there can’t be a useful answer to this. For some sites it might take minutes or hours, for others weeks or even months.

Answer (score 0):

You need to embed this into a webpage whose content is about the same event. You can find more information at:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data#markup-formats-and-placement

JSON-LD is the recommended format by Google at this point btw.

Comment: If I have update my reviews then how much time Google will take to reflect on results? any guesses??

Answer (score 0):

In this case "the best file" to put that code is in the **Rohit Patil Event** file. It should go somewhere between the head section of that webpage. I.e.

```
 <html> 
<head> 
..your json-ld code.. 
</head> 
</html>
```

Comment: If I have update my reviews then how much time Google will take to reflect on results? any guesses??

Comment: The time varies but you can accelerate the process telling Google that you want your page to be crawled again in the Search Console (webmaster tools) [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en).