# Where on the website should I put RDF/XML Schema.org code?

Tags: schema.org, rdf-xml

I'm trying to put Schema.org on a website. First I made JSON-LD but the website is not allowing any `script` in the `head` element. Then I converted it into RDF/XML format below.

Now, where on the website should I put this for Google to read it. Should I put in the `head` element?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
         xmlns:schema="http://schema.org/">

  <schema:Organization rdf:nodeID="genid1">
    <schema:name rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">National Public Radio</schema:name>
    <schema:sponsor>
      <schema:Organization>
        <schema:name rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">GloboCorp</schema:name>
        <schema:url rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/"/>
      </schema:Organization>
    </schema:sponsor>

    <schema:url rdf:resource="http://npr.org"/>
  </schema:Organization>

</rdf:RDF>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include it in the HTML document, you would have to use a `script` element (just like with JSON-LD). This `script` element [doesn’t have to be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28688394/1591669) part of the `head`, you can place it in the `body`. An alternative is to provide the RDF/XML in its own file and link it from the `head`, or offer it via content negotiation.

That said, **Google Search doesn’t support RDF/XML**. For their search result features, which make use of Schema.org, they only [support](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data#structured-data-guidelines) these syntaxes:

- JSON-LD (in `script`)
- Microdata
- RDFa