# Using JSON-LD for on-site reviews

Tags: html, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

I read the article [The Complete Guide to Creating On-Site Reviews + Testimonials Pages](https://moz.com/blog/the-complete-guide-to-creating-onsite-reviews-testimonials-pages). I would like to create my own solution on our website to collect reviews on our website that Google can find. I'm not 100% sure if I understand this correctly.

So I would create a form with appropriate inputs and take that user input and create a JSON-LD object in a  `<script>` tag and place that in the `head` of our `/reviews/` page. So each review listed on our `/reviews/` page would be in an array of JSON-LD objects, and that's how Google can find it?

Is it as simple as that? Placing the JSON-LD in the `<head>` with the correct data?

[This site](https://barbaraoliverandco.com/reviews-testimonials/) was used as an example on the article I linked. They use a third-party service that is basically doing what I am going to set out to do. I don't see the data in the `head` when viewing source, but I guess it's a good practice to hide the JSON-LD somewhere? I see a JSON-LD `script`, but it's empty.

Can someone help me understand this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to provide machine-readable structured data about the reviews, using the vocabulary [Schema.org](https://schema.org/). Three syntaxes are supported: JSON-LD, Microdata, RDFa.

[See a comparison](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/328711/63183). With Microdata and RDFa, you would add HTML attributes to the existing markup for the reviews. With JSON-LD, you would add the structured data in a separate `script` element and leave the review markup untouched.

This `script` element [can be in the `head` or in the `body`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28688394/1591669). By default, it’s visually hidden no matter where it’s placed.

If you provide such structured data, consumers (like Google Search) may make use of it. For example, Google Search offers the [Review rich result](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review) feature. Their documentation describes which Schema.org types/properties are needed to qualify for it.