# Including JSON-LD in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, seo, components, json-ld

I am currently creating a blog website and want to describe my blog posts using JSON-LD. As I am using React, blog posts are loaded dynamically using react router and content to display is fetched from server when a user clicks a specific blog post link.

Inside the blog post component e.g the component rendered when a user visits `/post/1` my initial idea is to include the JSON-LD within the returned component markup. e.g, somewhere within the render function have:

```
   <script type="application/ld+json">
      {
        {
          "@context": "http://schema.org",
          "@type": "NewsArticle",
          "mainEntityOfPage": {
            "@type": "WebPage",
            "@id": "https://google.com/article"
          },
          "headline": "Article headline",
          "image": [
            "https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg",
            "https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg",
            "https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg"
          ],
          "datePublished": "2015-02-05T08:00:00+08:00",
          "dateModified": "2015-02-05T09:20:00+08:00",
          "author": {
            "@type": "Person",
            "name": "John Doe"
          },
          "publisher": {
            "@type": "Organization",
            "name": "Google",
            "logo": {
              "@type": "ImageObject",
              "url": "https://google.com/logo.jpg"
            }
          },
          "description": "A most wonderful article"
        }
      }
      </script>
```

My question is, what is the best practice for this? Can search engines pick this up or should I be injecting this into the head section? Can they pick that up? If not, how are you meant to use JSON-LD appropriately in a single page application?

Thanks!

Comment: I don’t know React, so I’m not sure what the core of the question is really about, but maybe this helps: [JSON-LD in `head` or `body`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28687653/1591669) ··· [support of JSON-LD added client-side?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29064209/1591669)

Comment: I'm essentially asking if dynamically inserting JSON-LD into the DOM after page load is valid and whether or search engines can retrieve and use this information. Essentially the same as ajax request -> create json-ld script -> add to document body

Comment: Thanks for the links I will check them out!

Comment: @Eladian injection is valid BUT the indexers will not see it. therefore, it's counterproductive.

Comment: @Eladian - I have the same question and wondering if you had any conclusion on your question?

Answer (score 0):

Since this hasnt been answered yet, I believe JSONLD can be inserted anywhere in the DOM and it will still be indexed. Looks like its [answered in this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28687653/schema-org-json-ld-where-to-place)