# How to add schemas in Next.js 13 app router

Tags: javascript, next.js, schema, next.js13, app-router

**tl;dr**

Next.js 13's `/app` router's `layout` and `page` routing changes how we add content to the `<head>`. How can I add a schema script to each page? Next.js will automatically compile `<head>` tags placed in any `layout` or `page` into a single `<head>`.

## The goal

Just like in any website with great SEO, I want to include a schema script in the head of each page.

### The history

Normally, this would be as easy as writing it in the `<head>` like so:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<head>
  <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      // ... the rest
    }
  </script>
</head>
```

Then, with the Next.js `/pages` directory it was a little different. It always felt weird to me to have to use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute, but at least it worked.

```
// index.tsx
import Head from 'next/head'
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <Head>
      <script id="schema" type="application/ld+json" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: `
        {
          "@context": "https://schema.org",
          // ... the rest
        }
      `}} />
    </Head>
  )
}
```

### The issue

Now with the introduction of the `/app` router, we've got great, new, simplified ways to set metadata, without having to directly import the `<head>` through `next/head`. In fact, the `next/head` component shouldn't be used in the `/app` router.

So the question becomes...

#### How do we access the `<head>` on a page-per-page basis?

I was hoping the Next.js team would have already thought about this, and added schema to the new `metadata` variable, or even it's own variable, but they don't seem to have plans to do this as far as I can tell.

I tried adding a `<head>` to the `page` and unfortunately, it doesn't properly merge into the `<head>`. So far the only thing I can thing to do would be to add the schema to each `layout`, but what a hassle that would be to have an individual layout for each page.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Most likely this feature is not of high priority for Next.js team because JSON-LD data can be rendered anywhere in the page body - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28687653/schema-org-json-ld-where-to-place ; and in fact that’s what Next.js documentation recommends - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata#json-ld

Comment: @IgorDanchenko Thank you! I didn't realize it could go anywhere inside the body too. All of the documentation I've seen on schemas has always said put it in the `<head>`. That's super helpful.

Comment: Not everything can go anywhere. It should have been a priority before shoving this unfinished version down our throats.

Comment: @MarekMaurizio If you have a better solution, feel free to share.

Comment: @andrilla gladly, at the moment I use the pages router.

Comment: @MarekMaurizio Right. What a great solution to a question regarding the app router.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Official Next.js Answer

The Next.js team has official documentation on this at [Metadata – JSON-LD](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata#json-ld). (Putting the schema in the `<head>` is not required, as demonstrated in the code)

### Code Example

Using a JS object and a `<script>` tag, we can add the JSON-LD on any page.

```
// page.tsx

export default async function Page({ params }) {
  const product = await getProduct(params.id)
 
  const jsonLd = {
    '@context': 'https://schema.org',
    '@type': 'Product',
    name: product.name,
    image: product.image,
    description: product.description,
  }
 
  return (
    <section>
      {/* Add JSON-LD to your page */}
      <script
        type="application/ld+json"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: JSON.stringify(jsonLd) }}
      />
      {/* ... */}
    </section>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you might have the answer already but for all of us that might be looking for a solution to the same problem:

```js
import Head from 'next/head';

function ProductPage() {
  function addProductJsonLd() {
    return {
      __html: `{
      "@context": "https://schema.org/",
      "@type": "Product",
      "name": "Executive Anvil",
      "image": [
        "https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg",
        "https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg",
        "https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg"
       ],
      "description": "Sleeker than ACME's Classic Anvil, the Executive Anvil is perfect for the business traveler looking for something to drop from a height.",
      "sku": "0446310786",
      "mpn": "925872",
      "brand": {
        "@type": "Brand",
        "name": "ACME"
      },
      "review": {
        "@type": "Review",
        "reviewRating": {
          "@type": "Rating",
          "ratingValue": "4",
          "bestRating": "5"
        },
        "author": {
          "@type": "Person",
          "name": "Fred Benson"
        }
      },
      "aggregateRating": {
        "@type": "AggregateRating",
        "ratingValue": "4.4",
        "reviewCount": "89"
      },
      "offers": {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "url": "https://example.com/anvil",
        "priceCurrency": "USD",
        "price": "119.99",
        "priceValidUntil": "2020-11-20",
        "itemCondition": "https://schema.org/UsedCondition",
        "availability": "https://schema.org/InStock"
      }
    }
  `,
    };
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>My Product</title>
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="Super product with free shipping."
          key="desc"
        />
        <script
          type="application/ld+json"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={addProductJsonLd()}
          key="product-jsonld"
        />
      </Head>
      <h1>My Product</h1>
      <p>Super product for sale.</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProductPage;
```

Here is the link with more info in the next.js documentation! https://nextjs.org/learn/seo/rendering-and-ranking/metadata

Comment: This does not answer the question. This only works in the `/pages` directory. The question is specifically about the `/app` directory. You cannot use the `next/head` component in the `/app` directory, as shown here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components. There is no `<Head>` equivalent.